# Timber/Twig showing: "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Twig\CacheExtension\CacheStrategy.."

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

After seeing a critical error (white screen of death) on my live WordPress site, I turned on debugging in wp-config.php and see the following error message.
I have not changed anything on the site, but plugins are set to auto-update.
(edit) Timber is on v1.19, which is the latest version and may have
broken something.

---

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Twig\CacheExtension\CacheStrategy\GenerationalCacheStrategy::__construct() must be an instance of Twig\CacheExtension\CacheProviderInterface, instance of Timber\Cache\WPObjectCacheAdapter given, called in /home/runcloud/webapps/vitahomes/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/lib/Loader.php on line 282 and defined in /home/runcloud/webapps/vitahomes/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/cache-extension/lib/Twig/CacheExtension/CacheStrategy/GenerationalCacheStrategy.php:43 Stack trace: #0 /home/runcloud/webapps/vitahomes/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/lib/Loader.php(282): Twig\CacheExtension\CacheStrategy\GenerationalCacheStrategy->__construct(Object(Timber\Cache\WPObjectCacheAdapter), Object(Timber\Cache\KeyGenerator), 0) #1 /home/runcloud/webapps/vitahomes/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/lib/Loader.php(182): Timber\Loader->_get_cache_extension() #2 /home/runcloud/webapps/vitahomes/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/lib/Loader.php(70): Timber\Loader->get_twig() in /home/runcloud/webapps/vitahomes/wp-content/plugins/timber-library/vendor/twig/cache-extension/lib/Twig/CacheExtension/CacheStrategy/GenerationalCacheStrategy.php on line 43

There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

---

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 2):

Solved here:
https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2494

I used a Timber/Twig starter theme that had composer autoload in functions.php
Once that was commented the site loads without error.